# creating exe using cx_freeze, but move exe to root directory to deploy

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I created a new script with cx_freeze's template. Then I'm running `python setup.py build` to create the exe. If I move `main.exe` to the root folder `cx_freeze test` it will fail to run.

All I want is to move .exe up 1 or two directories. 
Here's my code:

**main.py**

```
foo = input("Complete")
```

**setup.py:**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(
    packages = [],
    excludes = [],
    includes = ["atexit"]
)
    # include_files=[]

base = 'Console'

executables = [
    Executable('main.py', base=base, targetName = 'main.exe')
]

setup(name='freeze test',
      version = '1',
      description = '.',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

[image]
I thought http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files might have some help, but since the files are in the subdirectory, I can't use `os` module?

Answer (score 0):

That feature is not available in 4.x but will be available in 5.x when it is made available. The current source has this capability so if you can compile it you can have it today; otherwise, you'll need to wait for the official release which I hope will be soon.